# Dark Mode for Economics.SE

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Is it possible to implement dark mode on Economics.SE similar to what's available on StackOverflow, please? Below is a sample screenshot of how it looks like on SO:

[image]

And one can toggle dark mode on or off based on personal preference:

[image]

Comment: This would be nice, I was wondering about it too. I even asked about it on TL few months ago but I was told that they don't plan to roll that out for beta sites in near future. I tagged this as status review so some CMs can have a look at it but I would not get your hopes up

Comment: @1muflon1 Not sure when or if at all this will be implemented on other non-beta sites, but I've posted on [ELU meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15299/50044) as well.

Answer (score 2):

We don't have plans of rolling out Dark Mode to the rest of the network at this time, and can't roll it out on a per-site basis. As such, I'm [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)'ing this request.